# Why are online minifiers changing my code?

Tags: javascript, css, minify

Why are online minifiers changing my code?

I have on my original code ...

```
if (typeof Object.create !== "function") {
    Object.create = function (obj) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = obj;
    return new F();
};
}
(function ($, window, document) {

var Carousel = {
    init : function (options, el) {
        var ba ........
```

and the minifier returns...

```
"function"!=typeof Object.create&&(Object.create=function(t){function e(){}return e.prototype=t,new e}),function(t,e,o){var i={init:function(e,o){var i=this;i.$elem=t(o),i.options=t.extend({},t.fn.owlCarousel.options,i.$elem.data(),e),i.userOptions=e,i.loadContent()},loadContent:function(){var e,o=this;"function"==t....
```

Can I get a recommendation for an online minifier that respects my code and only eliminates comments and unnecessary spaces for my CSS and JAVASCRIPTS?

Comment: wow instant vote down for what I think is a legit question..

Comment: They do not change your code. It does what it has done before. It just minifies your code. That 's the job of minifiers.

Comment: And many times things stop working because of it.. I just need comments and unnecessary spaces eliminated.. not altering the code..

Comment: you need to understand that some people may downvote this question cause before you post your question here you should make sure that you do some research before posting it but to answer your question I would agree with @Marcel that is basically how a minifier works if you want to avoid the changing of variable names you may have to see if the tool your using for minification have a support for this set of rule or if not you may really need to do it manually.

Comment: I did research.. when I didn't find a straight answer I asked the community.. But thanks all .. I love stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really change your code!
It uglifies your code, mangles names and properties and function names. That's really a minifier does.
If you don't want any of this options you can use https://www.uglifyjs.net/ that allows you to choose your options.